# Dockerfile creation

Tags: dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
MAINTAINER rajendrachowdary40@gmail.com
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk
RUN apt-get install -y  curl
ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr
RUN mkdir /opt/tomcat/
WORKDIR /opt/tomcat
RUN curl -O  https://www-eu.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.5.40/bin/apache-tomcat-8.5.40.tar.gz
CMD tar xvzf apache-tomcat-8.5.40.tar.gz -C /opt/tomcat/
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.40/bin/startup.sh && bash"]
```

> root@ip-172-31-27-71:~/docker# docker run -it raja963/new-img:latest
>
> docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.40/bin/startup.sh && bash\": stat /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.40/bin/startup.sh && bash: no such file or directory": unknown.

Comment: Next time try to properly format your code using the tools available

Answer (score 0):

> CMD tar xvzf apache-tomcat-8.5.40.tar.gz -C /opt/tomcat/

CMD and ENTRYPOINT are commands to be executed in a container, but not during image build. Also there can be only one. Your entrypoint is overriding the CMD.

Change this line

> RUN curl -O
>   https://www-eu.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.5.40/bin/apache-tomcat-8.5.40.tar.gz
>   CMD tar xvzf apache-tomcat-8.5.40.tar.gz -C /opt/tomcat/

into this

```
RUN curl -O https://www-eu.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.5.40/bin/apache-tomcat-8.5.40.tar.gz && \
    tar xvzf apache-tomcat-8.5.40.tar.gz -C /opt/tomcat/
```

It should do the trick for you.